# Is there a difference between setting a proxy to an empty string vs undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, undefined, undefined-behavior

What issues can arise from having a proxy become undefined when there is no process.env.HTTPS_PROXY vs an empty string?

```
const proxy = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY || '';
```

vs

```
const proxy = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY;
```

Comment: Any string operators later would not have to verify that the value is set.

Comment: And actually the usage of doing this and putting it in a variable, is most likely there for the D.R.Y principle and the or logic doesn't have to be repeated over and over through out the script.

Comment: Many issues can arise. If you don't show us the code that *uses* the `proxy` constant though, we cannot tell you which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is what you do afterwards:
Let's assume that `process.env.HTTPS_PROXY` is undefined:

```
const proxy = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY || '';
if (proxy.length > 7){
// something
} else {
// something else
}
```

will simply enter for the "else" part

```
const proxy = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY; 
if (proxy.length > 7){
// something
} else {
// something else
}
```

will throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: proxy is not defined`

and probably crash your app

Comment: Thank you Malarres!